# Howto add text at end of each line, containing text from the line with sed or awk?

Tags: awk, sed

For example I have next text message:

```
before1/endpoint-1
before2/endpoint-2
before3/endpoint-3
```

I want to output next:

```
before1/endpoint-1=somethingelse/endpoint-1
before2/endpoint-2=somethingelse/endpoint-2
before3/endpoint-3=somethingelse/endpoint-3
```

So I want to add `=somethingelse/` at the end of each line and then get the same endpoint from the line behind it.

I know I can add the part `=somethingelse/` as follows:

```
sed -i 's/$/=somethingelse\//' textfile
```

But howto add the samepart for the endpoint after it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's~\([^\/]*\)$~\1=somethingelse/\1~' file
before1/endpoint-1=somethingelse/endpoint-1
before2/endpoint-2=somethingelse/endpoint-2
before3/endpoint-3=somethingelse/endpoint-3
```

Answer (score 6):

there are many ways can achieve your goal, E.g. awk one-liner:

```
awk -F'/' '$0=$0"=somethingelse" FS $2'
```

or sed:

```
sed 's#/.*#&=somethingelse&#'
```

Comment: like your sed, quick and efficient

Comment: @NeronLeVelu sometimes greedy is handy.. :)